# Trying to convert a JSON file or string to a CSV file gives an empty CSV file

Tags: java, json, csv, google-sheets

So I am trying to convert a JSON file (Which I have exported as JSON using Google Sheets API) to a CSV file, even though there is a JSON file placed correctly at that location, or trying with instead a String, it either shows null pointer exception or returns an empty CSV file.

Sample JSON file:

```
{
  "range": "products!A1:E4",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "product_name",
      "price"
    ],
    [
      "Rugrats - Bedtime Bash [VHS]",
      "36.95"
    ],
    [
      "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II - The Secret of the Ooze [VHS]",
      "29.89"
    ],
    [
      "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II - The Secret of the Ooze [VHS]",
      "29.89"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The sample code I am trying to use here for converting them to CSV,

```
JSONObject output = new JSONObject(<String or file location that holds JSON file>);
File finalFile=new File(<Destination file path>);
JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("values");
String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(finalFile, csv);
```

Did I make any mistake in code or should I handle this JSON with different Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write directly from the Sheets API response (this example was extracted from the [Java Sheet API quick-start](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java))

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "<SHEET_ID>";
    final String range = "<SHEET_RANGE>";
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        /* Create a new writer */
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data.csv");
        for (List<Object> list : values) {
            /* Building the string */
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append(list.get(0).toString() + ",");
            str.append(list.get(1).toString() + "\n");
            writer.write(str.toString());
        }
        /* Closing the writer */
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

In any case, if you are reading the JSON object correctly, the mechanism would be exactly the same.

###### Updated

If you want to read directly from JSON you can use this example (using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)):

```java
public class SheetResponse {
    private String range;
    private String majorDimensions; 
    private List<List<Object>> values;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    var gson = new Gson();
    var reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("test.json"));
    SheetResponse sR = gson.fromJson(reader, SheetResponse.class);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data.csv");
    for (List<Object> list : sR.values) {
        /* Building the string */
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append(list.get(0).toString() + ",");
        str.append(list.get(1).toString() + "\n");
        writer.write(str.toString());
    }
    /* Closing the writer */
    writer.close();
}
```

###### Updated for the general case

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    var gson = new Gson();
    var reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("test.json"));
    SheetResponse sR = gson.fromJson(reader, SheetResponse.class);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data.csv");

    for (int i = 0; i < sR.values.size(); i++) {
        var valueRow = sR.values.get(i);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < valueRow.size(); j++) {
            if (j == valueRow.size() - 1) {
                str.append(valueRow.get(j).toString() + "\n");
            } else {
                str.append(valueRow.get(j).toString() + ",");
            }
        }
        writer.write(str.toString());
    }
    /* Closing the writer */
    writer.close();
}
```

###### Documentation

- [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)
- [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Does Gson and JSONReader require any maven dependencies?

Comment: Yes, as you can read in the [github](https://github.com/google/gson#download) page of GSON. If you consider my answer to be correct, consider accepting it for visibility.

Comment: What about other cases where there are more pairs, what should I do?

Comment: Just thinking about that, updated at the answer